# What's the difference between `set-face-background` and `custom-set-faces`?

Tags: faces, spacemacs

I get an error, `Invalid face: helm-selection`, using `dotspacemacs/user-config`:

```
(set-face-background 'helm-selection "#EEAD0E")
```

It runs fine if I manually enter it using `helm-M-x`.

However, I get no errors (during startup) for the following in `dotspacemacs/user-config`:

```
 (custom-set-faces
    '(helm-selection ((t (:background "#EEAD0E" :foreground "#222226"))))
  )
```

I've read the documentation on both face functions, but I still counldn't figure out the reason for the different behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty clear: `helm-M-x` must cause face `helm-selection` to be defined. Otherwise, it is not defined by default.

The error message tells you that symbol `helm-selection' is not associated with a face.

If you had tried just `(set-face-background 'highlight "#EEAD0E")` you would have seen that there is no problem, because face `highlight` is predefined.  Your problem is that nothing has defined face `helm-selection`.

The reason you don't see a problem with `custom-set-faces` is that it does not require the face to be defined ahead of time. It just applies of face specs (specifications that are lists) to the `user` theme. It does not try to change, itself, an existing face.